# Use an Enum defined in another script

Tags: powershell, enums

How can I define an **Enum global** to use it *outside* of the defined scope?
I created a script which imports another script (including all global functions, variables and enums)

```
Enum CrudFlag
{
  Undefined
  Create
  Read
  Update
  Delete
}
```

Comment: If you define this enum in a .ps1 and dotsource it within another script, you are able to access the enum.

Comment: I do dotsource the "core" script _.\Core\Import-CmdbCore.ps1_ and its still not working

Comment: did you dotsourced it using `. .\Core\Import-CmdbCore.ps1` (with two dots)?

Comment: no now its working, haven't known that there is a difference. can you explain me the difference or provide me some information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import your script using **dotsourceing**:

> Each script runs in its own scope. The functions, variables, aliases,
>   and drives that are created in the script exist only in the script
>   scope. You cannot access these items or their values in the scope in
>   which the script runs.
>
> To run a script in a different scope, you can specify a scope, such as
>   Global or Local, or you can dot source the script.
>
> The dot sourcing feature lets you run a script in the current scope
>   instead of in the script scope. When you run a script that is dot
>   sourced, the  commands in the script run as though you had typed them
>   at the command  prompt. The functions, variables, aliases, and drives
>   that the script  creates are created in the scope in which you are
>   working. After the script runs, you can use the created items and
>   access their values in your session.
>
> To dot source a script, type a dot (.) and a space before the script
>   path

[Source.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx)